# In P4V, what does the monitor with two tildes icon mean?

Tags: icons, perforce, p4v

I recently noticed this icon [image] being shown on my workspace, where it used to not have the tildes. What does this mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The waves are the symbol for a stream.  I think having them overlaid on a workspace means the workspace is associated with a stream (rather than being a "classic" workspace with a manually specified depot mapping).